# CSS triangle at the end of an element

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I have this code that I'm listing below where the elements for the categories are.

I need to modify the bottom border to look like this picture:

[image: Text]

Is this possible using after and before pseudo-elements or will I need to add another element to the html?

Thank you.

```css
body {
  background-color: #f3ece5;
}

.categories-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    gap: 25px;
    padding: 40px;
}

.categories-grid .single-category {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      flex-direction: column;
      padding: 20px 0;
      border: 1px solid #e2d2c2;
      background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<section class="categories">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="categories-grid">
      <div class="single-category">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x140" alt="image" />
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <div class="link">
          <a href="#">somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
        
           <div class="single-category">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x140" alt="image" />
          <h3>Title</h3>
          <div class="link">
            <a href="#">somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        
           <div class="single-category">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x140" alt="image" />
          <h3>Title</h3>
          <div class="link">
            <a href="#">somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: A quick solution to creating the triangle would be to use the `clip-path`-property: `.single-category { clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 96%, 50% 100%, 0 96%); }`. You can't use the `border`-property the way you want it to though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rely on both pseudo element with a skew transformation. Each pseudo element will define half the element shape.

```css
body {
  background-color: #f3ece5;
}

.categories-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 25px;
  padding: 40px;
}

.categories-grid .single-category {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #e2d2c2;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.categories-grid .single-category:before,
.categories-grid .single-category:after {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  border: solid #e2d2c2;
}
.categories-grid .single-category:before {
  top:0;
  left:0;
  transform: skewY(8deg);
  transform-origin: right;
  border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;
}
.categories-grid .single-category:after {
  top:0;
  right:0;
  transform: skewY(-8deg);
  transform-origin: left;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="categories">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="categories-grid">
      <div class="single-category">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x140" alt="image" />
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <div class="link">
          <a href="#">somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="single-category">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x140" alt="image" />
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <div class="link">
          <a href="#">somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="single-category">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x140" alt="image" />
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <div class="link">
          <a href="#">somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Damn, that's a nice solution!

Comment: Temani, I could able to see that you close my question https://stackoverflow.com/q/75522294/15916627 by mentioning it as duplicate to my previous question. But believe me I am struggling with this to get a solution. It is not exact duplicate and I just wish to make responsive alone in a separate question. But if you could able to help me in providing a solution in any of the question it would be really great.